# 3D Vector object not functioning right

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I have been working on creating an RPG combat sim for code-practice. A single 'battle' constitutes a 3D vector based on number of rounds,number of fighter and number of Rolls (per fighter in each round) in that order. After hours of searching I have put together this code. I am aware there are easier ways to accomplish this (boost / matrix etc..) but I want to finish this and learn where my `STL::vector` manipulation is going wrong

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Combat{
    private:
        int numberOfRounds;
        int numberOfCombatants;
        int numberOfRolls;
        int sidesDie;            
        vector <vector <vector <int> > > result;

    public:
        void printMenu();
        void battle();
        void printResult();
        int roll(int die);
};
int Combat::roll(int die)
{
    die=sidesDie;
    srand(time(0));
    int r=(1+rand()%die);
    return r;

void Combat::battle(){
    cout<<setw(10)<<" Computing results of battle ...\n";
    int i,j,k;
    for (i=0;i<numberOfRounds;++i){
        cout<<"Round number "<<i+1;
        for(j=0;j<numberOfCombatants;++j){
            for(k=0;k<numberOfRolls;++k){
                result[i][j].push_back(roll(sidesDie));

            }
            cout<<endl;
        }

        cout<<endl;

      }
}
```

The code above is supposed to create a 3D vector 'result' which should store dice-rolls inside cells per player per round. It crashes during execution without showing an error. i suspect the bug is in the way i am storing values inside the 3d vector

Comment: And your question is? What is the problem? What do you expect it to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: You need to initialize this "result" vector. result[i] will fail because result is zero-length vector. Same for result[i][j].

Comment: You're making the same mistake in all of your questions; you're building a large, complex program and *then* seeing if it works. It's a common rookie error. You should start small (say, with 1D), get that working perfectly, then build up (to 2D, then 3D). And *never add to code that doesn't work*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - your result variable is a vector of vector of vector of ints.  In your battle loop, you are attempting to push_back into the innermost vector, but the outer two vectors don't have any contents defined yet.

You'll need to push_back an entry for i and j as well (of the appropriate subtype, e.g. vector < vector < int > >, and then vector < int >, to use the vector in this fashion.

**edit**

For instance:

```
int i,j,k;
vector<vector<int>> iType;
vector<int> jType;
for (i=0;i<numberOfRounds;++i)
{
    cout<<"Round number "<<i+1;
    result.push_back( iType );
    for(j=0;j<numberOfCombatants;++j)
    {
        result[i].push_back( jType );
        for(k=0;k<numberOfRolls;++k)
        {
            result[i][j].push_back(roll(sidesDie));

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    cout<<endl;

  }
```

Comment: I tried using this code but didn't work. not sure how to get this to work either.void Combat::battle(){
    cout<<setw(10)<<" Computing results of battle ...\n";
    int i,j,k;
    for (i=0;i<numberOfRounds;++i){
            cout<<"Round number "<<i+1;
            result.push_back(i);
            for(j=0;j<numberOfCombatants;++j){
                result[i].push_back(j);
                for(k=0;k<numberOfRolls;++k){
                    result[i][j].push_back(roll(sidesDie));

                }

            }
            cout<<endl;
        }

        cout<<endl;

      }

Comment: That's because you're pushing the wrong type into the outer vectors.  The result.push_back will need to be of a vector< vector < int > > type, and the result[i] will need to be a vector< int > type.  You might want to reconsider your approach, though, as this is a bit cumbersome.  I'd recommend defining a class or struct Combatants holding the number and number of rolls, and placing these in a single vector< Combatants >, which has one entry per round.

Comment: Thanks for all your time. Not working yet. Before i adopt your given approach i will post the latest code-edit anyway. thanks for helping a noob  :: for (i=0;i<numberOfRounds;++i){
        result.push_back(vector <vector <int> >);
            cout<<"Round number "<<i+1;

            for(j=0;j<numberOfCombatants;++j){
                result.push_back(vector<int>);
               
                for(k=0;k<numberOfRolls;++k){
                    result.push_back(roll(sidesDie));

                }

            }
            cout<<endl;
        }

Comment: That's close. The vector (and all std library containers) work using "copy" semantics.  You need to provide a variable to the push_back function, and not a type, so if you make a couple empty variables of those types before your loop, you can push_back a copy of them.  I updated my response to include a sample of this.